# Python/Kivy: popup content not visible

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy-language

I'm creating an application in Python and its GUI with the use of Kivy. I have a problem when I want to open a pop-up. It opens correctly, but its content is not visible. The popup is empty. I'm writing the application with the main script in python and the use of kv language for the gui. Below are the scripts:

main.py:

```
class PopupW(FloatLayout):
pass

class WindowLayout(BoxLayout):
    def open_pop_up(self, btn_id):
        if self.ids.analysis_type_btn.text == btn_id:
            self.analysis_type_pop_up()
        else:
            if self.ids.config_cond_btn.text == btn_id:
                self.config_cond_pop_up()
            else:
                self.config_par_pop_up()

    def analysis_type_pop_up(self):
        show_pop_up()

class WindowCreation(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'GUI_contents/guistructure.kv')
        )

def show_pop_up():
    show = PopupW()
    popupwindow = Popup(title="Popup window", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popupwindow.open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WindowCreation().run()
```

main_gui.kv:

```
WindowLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: analysis_type_btn
        text: 'Analysis type'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.08, 'y': 0.8}
        size_hint: 0.38, 0.1
        on_press: root.open_pop_up('Analysis type')
```

popup_gui.kv:

```
PopupW:
    Label:
        text: "You pressed"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 1}
    Button:
        text: "You press"
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.1}
```

Does someone know where I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.